# What do we call one's personal circle of knowledge and who wrote about it?

Tags: reference-request, terminology

Somebody reached out to me with the following funny phrase:

> If you ever laugh at a person telling you a joke in your dreams you’re laughing at your own joke

([Source](http://just-shower-thoughts.tumblr.com/post/131587796874/if-you-ever-laugh-at-a-person-telling-you-a-joke))

I'd like to elaborate on this concept of one's personal circle of knowledge, the personal bubble that encompasses everything that a person knows, and the process by which new knowledge becomes part of someone's world.

I realize that this was probably written about extensively, but I don't know which is the correct term for it, nor who is a good source about it.

Comment: Stream of conciousness, Husserl

Comment: I voted up, not sure why others thought this was a bad question. It could be flushed out more, but it was a reference request.  Oh, in addition to below, there may be something in Gestalt, the psychological outgrowth of phenomenology. I am not very familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the above, the psychological problem of "originating new knowledge" may actually begin with Kant's defense and analysis of the "synthetic *a priori*," though Kant would never describe this as "psychology." And I don't know what, if anything, he had to say about dreams.

Given the *a priori* rules necessary to all possible experience, we do indeed construct or "synthesize" not only the "experience" of our apparent world, but such "possible experiences" as those in dreams. I myself have had dreams that entail something like "plot suspense" and I always wondered, how could my own mind create suspense for itself, withholding the ending? It is the same with the joke, where the mind "takes itself by surprise." I am not sure, but perhaps Kant's treatment of aesthetic judgment is most relevant here.

Another reference in the later, phenomenological tradition could be Bachelard. He writes about the operations of the "poetic" image and the paradoxical "poesis" of constructing what is "new" within poetry. How can the poetic image be entirely "new" and yet also "recognized"? A deeper (or transcendental) categorical organization is already at work, so the image, joke, or "surprise" appears not as "purely new," but as a "negation" in a formal structure, like the empty gap in a jigsaw puzzle that suddenly identifies the missing piece, if that makes sense.

We cannot tickle ourselves, so how can the mind surprise itself or "laugh at its own joke"? Because "outside" surprises and "new" experiences are set in motion and brought before our attention by our own synthesizing capacities or "bubble blowing," or, in Kant's terms, our ceaseless transcendental "unification of apperception." A dream is full of shocks, apparent externalities, new entities, and phenomenal surprises, yet "all in our mind." Thus, it reveals something of the raw "synthesizing" operations behind "all possible" experiences.

Comment: +1. I think you may have grasped the concept of my question better that I had explained it. I'll look into Kant's approach since it seems more aligned with what I was thinking, but I'll also check on the other sources. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Well, good luck with Kant. I wish I could recommend a simpler source. I still struggle to process Kant and am always asking "was it worth it"? If you are actually interested in "philosophy" per say, most people agree, you have to go through Kant. But you can answer your question by shorter routes, in psychology, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As a general answer, all that is linked to "Phenomenology". You could describe this type of philosophy as an attempt to describe and destinguish the contents and mechanics of conciousness.

Starting from Husserl, modernized by what is called "philosophy of mind" with Ryle, Nagel and Searle as some examples.

For an overview just read [the SEP article to phenomenology](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/phenomenology/#6).

Comment: @Alpha be a little careful with Phenomenology as it pretty much turned into Transcendental Idealism and ended up splitting into multiple factions.  It won't hurt to compare this to Phenomenalism.

Answer (score 0):

> the personal bubble that encompasses everything that a person knows

is named *memory*.

> the process by which new knowledge becomes part of someone's world

is named *learning*.

Hence in textbooks about *Cognitive Psychology* you find information about both issues.

**Note**. To me the connection between these two issues and your introduction with the dream-example is not quite clear. Probably I missed your point. Please let me know.

Comment: Hi Jo! Thanks for the answer. I think memory + learning would leave much to gray areas as there is knowledge that is accessible to me and knowledge that is not. For example, I don't recall my father's phone number, but I know I can look it up from my contact list. Would that be in my circle of knowledge? Based on the memory definition, it would not, but based on the feasibility of that knowledge, it may take a different answer. I was asking about which discipline/current explores these gray areas. Does this distinction help? (I'm sorry if it doesn't, it's hard to ask without the right words.)

Comment: @Alpha You did not define the meaning of "circle of knowledge". Hence I cannot answer how your example with the telephon number relates to this concept. - But when taking your two defintions highlighted in my reply, then the answer to your example seems easy: The telephon number of your father is not stored in your *memory*, but the location, where to find it, is stored in your *memory*. Hence you can go and *learn* the number.

Comment: Exact. That circle of knowledge does not have a definite boundary since there is achievable knowledge and unachievable knowledge, for me, some of them more accessible than others. It is up to me to learn it or to leave it as a particular piece of knowledge that I can use without learning. This categorization of the knowledge I have, plus my way of interacting with it -- that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: PS: I realized I did explain myself poorly, I apologize for that. I'm still in doubt whether I was able to get my point across.

Comment: @Alpha it sounds like you're drawing lines between different types of knowledge, and I'm not sure those lines are valid.  I'm currently reading Gilbert Rhyle's "The Concept of Mind" and he talks about "Knowing How" and "Knowing That" and uses various examples where people consider performance of one kind of act to be knowledge and performance of another not to be. Yet the difference is in the postulated mental state of the agent.  We get into some really nebulous territory pretty quickly when we do this.